# How to store rechargeable batteries

Tags: batteries, storage

I like using rechargeable [NiMH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel%E2%80%93metal_hydride_battery) batteries (AA and AAA) rather than buying single-use ones, for obvious reasons. The issue is, I often have to prematurely discard them because they leak. I suspect it has to do with storing them together in the same box, and with the weather (I live in a sub-tropical region where temperatures can get very high and there is a dry season and a wet season).

How should I store my rechargeable batteries in order to really use them to their full potential in the long term?

Comment: I started to write an answer, but there is so many conflicting advice that I gave up. I suggest you [google all these yourself](https://www.google.nl/search?q=storing+nimh+batteries), and **follow links through to the actual recommendations from the manufacturers**. There are too many unreferenced opinions. (That goes for Jason's answer here as well, sorry). If you  come to an unambigious conclusion it may be worth self-answering your question here, with all these references.

Answer (score 1):

Leaking AA / AAA batteries are mostly due to overcharge when you use those chargers that charge them in pairs. See picture below for example.

Get a dedicated slow charger that is able to charge single cell, that way you'll able to safely charge your battery to full without overcharging. Never get those fast charger as they tend to heat up your battery to much and may damage it.

As for storing, keep them in a cool dry place.

[image]

Comment: Interesting answer. Could you provide a reference?